# Button click causing null pointer

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

[image]Every time I click on the button, the app crashes. I have trouble finding the bug, but I'm sure it has to do something with either the onClickListener, or the onClick function.

Note: I'm using Parse API for some back end stuff. But I highly doubt it has anything to do with any of the Parse stuff.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends Activity {

    protected EditText mUserName;
    protected EditText mPassword;
    protected EditText mEmail;
    protected Button mSignUpButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mSignUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);

        mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = mUserName.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();

                username = username.trim();
                password = password.trim();
                email = email.trim();

                if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                           .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                           .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else{

                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                    newUser.setUsername(username);
                    newUser.setPassword(password);
                    newUser.setEmail(email);
                    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                            if(e == null){
                                // success
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                       .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sign_up, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's my Log Cat:

```
04-14 14:19:05.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-14 14:19:05.881:
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): Process: com.ebad.ribbit, PID: 1156 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): java.lang.NullPointerException 04-14 14:19:05.881:
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at com.ebad.ribbit.SignUpActivity$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:40) 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 04-14 14:19:05.881:
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 04-14 14:19:05.881:
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 04-14 14:19:05.881:
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 04-14 14:19:05.881: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 04-14 14:19:05.881:
E/AndroidRuntime(1156): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

As requested, here is line 40:

```
String username = mUserName.getText().toString();
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the log cat after adding `Log.i(TAG, mUserName == null ? "mUserName is null" : mUserName.getText() == null ? "mUserName.getText() is null" : "nothing is null");`  :

```
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318): Process: com.ebad.ribbit, PID: 1318
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at com.ebad.ribbit.SignUpActivity$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:43)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-14 15:21:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(1318):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT 3:

Upon Request, here is my activity_sign_up.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SignUpActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userNameField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userNameField"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordField"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signupButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button_label" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Line 40 of SignUpActivity.java

Comment: I'd guess one of your calls to `.getText().toString()` is what's throwing the NPE, if the text is `null`, `toString()` will throw that exception.

Comment: I double clicked on that and it took me to those lines involving those lines. However, the fields are not null as I put in something, but still get the same errors.

Comment: Please, post line 40 of SignUpActivity.java.

Comment: Edit has been made to show line 40

Comment: Then can you just put 
---------- `Log.i(TAG, mUserName == null ? "mUserName is null" : mUserName.getText() == null ? "mUserName.getText() is null" : "nothing is null");` --------------
at line 39?

Comment: Agreed with @uDevel, also add some more logs 
   Log.i("DEBUG", username + " " + password + " " + email);

Comment: @uDevel I made the edit.

Comment: @KalelWade, please see the post now after the edit.

Comment: The log you attached doesn't show @uDevel or my log, attach what your new code looks like and what line 43 is.

Comment: Did the log even appear before the exception?
What line is 43 now?

Comment: @KalelWade, apologies. I only added uDevel's log. I'll add yours now.

Comment: Line 43 goes back to the .toString().getText()

Comment: Then can you post the log before the exception where my code run?

Comment: It's not logging it anything at all.

Comment: @uDevel, I posted the log before the .toString().getText() lines.

Comment: LOL, this doesn't even make sense, did you hide information log or something?

You know what?  Change it to Log.e just in case Log.i is hidden.

Comment: Agreed with @uDevel, your log should be seeing a true or false if you put his log in the right spot. Update your current code.

Comment: I just took a screen shot. Please see the edit.

Comment: Scroll up just above the error in the log and see if there was an ouput that said mUsername is null or musername.gettext is null or nothing is null. Log.i will output to this log if you didnt know this before.

Comment: You may need to click the different filters on the left side to see it.

Comment: This is very weird.  It should at least log something for line 42.

Restart the IDE.
Step through the code line by line, and stop before running the line 43 and show Log.  I am sorry, I might sound stupid, but it just doesn't make sense to not showing the Log.

Comment: @uDevel, IDE has been restarted numerous of times before posting this question. I even restarted my laptop twice. Let me step through.

Comment: Make sure you didn't filter out the log too.

Comment: I did notice this little message: "The JAR file has no source attachment"

Comment: The message was from the View$onClickListener class

Comment: Well, that's normal if you didn't attach source to it.
It doesn't cause this error.

Comment: I can't post code here.  Continue the talk in Answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50641/discussion-between-udevel-and-ebad-saghar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this please:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     if(mUserName != null && mPassword != null && mEmail != null && mUserName.getText() != null && mPassword.getText() != null && mEmail.getText() != null)
     {
          Your original code here.
     }
}
```

Update: 
Typo

```
 mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField); should be userNameField?  
 <EditText android:id="@+id/userNameField" ...
```

Comment: Wow, when I hit the signup button, nothing happens at all. Like nothing, not even crashing.

Comment: Exactly what I expected.  It's because at least one of those are null.

Comment: `mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);`
Why is usernameField  not userNameField?

`<EditText android:id="@+id/userNameField" ...`

Comment: I think that could be the problem, let me see.

Comment: It works. Wow, I can not believe I didn't see this typo, such as small mistake caused such a big head ache. Please leave an answer or edit your old one, so I can choose it.

Answer (score 1):

If `mUsername` is `null`, calling `getText()` on it will cause a `NullPointerException`. You should check that it's not null before doing this. Try changing to the following:

```
        if(mUserName == null || mPassword == null || mEmail == null){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                   .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                   .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

        String username = mUserName.getText().toString();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
        String email = mEmail.getText().toString();

        username = username.trim();
        password = password.trim();
        email = email.trim();
```

Comment: I did not leave them as null. I still got the same errors.

Comment: It still crashed after changing my code with your suggestion. Note: I am not leaving the fields empty, I am typing values in.

Comment: I agree you should be checking for the null before hand for better coding. However, I don't believe your current issue is due to the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Also make sure that SignUpActivity is declared in the app manifest. I guess make sure that all activities are set up in the manifest.

EDIT 1
If line 40 is the issue, then 
mUserName is null
or 
mUserName.getText() is null. So create a couple checks before hand and also add some debug logs to just verify that they are not null.

Make sure that R.layout.activity_sign_up has usernameField as an id. Also make sure in any other app/res/layout folders (ie layout-v14), that all R.layout.activity_sign_up has the edittext as well.

Answer (score 0):

If this errors occurred in your line 40, that means your are getting null from your EditText.

Try it in every place you are getting a string. At least it will save you from getting null pointer exception from EditText.

```
String username = String.valueOf(mUserName.getText());
String password = String.valueOf(mPassword.getText());
String email = String.valueOf(mEmail.getText());
```

Comment: can you upload your activity_sign_up.xml file too.